# Sorting in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'd like to know is it possible to make all selected options to appear at the top of the list, and then sort all selected options alphabetically?
Or at least just make them to appear at the top.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How would that work when you make a new selection? The list would re-order on-select, which would be rather unexpected and jarring for a user.

Comment: If you have an option to make the option disappear from the list on select, you can make that option to appear in the top of the list instead.

Comment: Oh so you want the select dropdown to close still, but when it's re-opened the selected items are at the top?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use `onChange` props in order to reorder your options stored in `state` like this:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  return a.label > b.label ? 1 : b.label > a.label ? -1 : 0;
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      options: options
    };
  }

  onChange = newOptions => {
    // take original options and remove selected options
    const stateOptions = options.filter(
      option => !newOptions.find(op => op === option)
    );
    // sort the selected options
    const orderedNewOptions = newOptions.sort(compare);
    this.setState({
      // concat the two arrays
      options: orderedNewOptions.concat(stateOptions)
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        options={this.state.options}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

You'll need to use `hideSelectedOptions={false}` to prevent selected options to be hidden.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj28n553o5).

Comment: how to do it on componentmount